# How do you change value of ExchangeConnectionMode (Outlook)

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am writing a test case  where I want to programatically set Outlook to be working offline and then test the reaction when outlook comes back online again. Is there anyway I can change the property Namespace.ExchangeConnectionMode?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `RDOSession.Offline` property - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm